# VSTS Code section does not show

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have created VSTS project, added 4 members and made them stakeholders. However no member can see Code section it is just now showing. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stakeholders don't have access to Code. They need to be at least Basic users.